# Nested nav toggle closing parent

Tags: html, jquery

I have a simple nav structure for a nav that has toggles to open and close sub-menus.  However, when I click on a nested menu the toggle works, but also closes the parent sub-menu.  How can I set it so that the parent doesn't close on the click of the nested menu?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  //Toggle sub-menus
  $('#menu .has-children').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).children('.sub-menu').slideToggle(500);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li class="has-children">item 2
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>sub-item 1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="has-children">item 3
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>sub-item 1</li>
      <li class="has-children">sub-item 2
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>sub-sub-item 1</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`event.preventDefault();` doesn't stop the event from traveling up the tree, you need to use `event.stopPropagation();` to stop the click from also triggering the click event listeners on parent elements.

(You could also add this to `li` inside sub menus without `.has-children`, to prevent them from closing parent menus, though that's unnecessary if those nav items link to other pages)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  //Toggle sub-menus
  $('#menu .has-children').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).children('.sub-menu').slideToggle(500);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li class="has-children">item 2
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>sub-item 1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="has-children">item 3
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>sub-item 1</li>
      <li class="has-children">sub-item 2
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>sub-sub-item 1</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```